# Nil when unwrapping an Optional Value in didBecomeActive()

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm incredibly confused with the following scenario in my `UIViewController`:

I have the following `@IBOutlet` which has a referencing outlet in my Storyboard.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var warningLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I then have this in my `AppDelegate`:

```
var mainViewController: BLEMainViewController?

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    let mainViewController: MainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as MainViewController
    let viewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    mainViewController.didBecomeActive()
}
```

When I set this inside `didBecomeActive()`

`self.warningLabel.text = "something"`

I get the following error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

However it works fine if I do the following inside:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.warningLabel.text = "something"
}
```

If I do `warningLabel.text = "something"` I get the same error.

If I do `warningLabel?.text = "something"` it doesn't actually get set.

If I do `self.warningLabel?.text = "something"` it doesn't actually get set.

What on earth am I doing wrong exactly?

**EDIT:**

Fixed by adding the following to my `UIViewController`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didBecomeActive", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Then it executes the `didBecomeActive()` function when the device becomes active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IBOutlet` is not yet initialized at the end of your `applicationDidBecomeActive`. So, you are trying to access a property (`.text`) of an object which is not initialized. This cause the error.

You don't have any error when calling `warningLabel?.text = "something"` because the `?` means that you want to access the `.text` property only if `warningLabel` is initialized (different from `nil`). That also explain why the text is not set in this case.

A good place to initialize your outlet property is in the `viewDidLoad` function of your `mainViewController`. At this point your outlet would be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding the following to my `UIViewController`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didBecomeActive", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Then it executes the `didBecomeActive()` function when the device becomes active.