# applicationWillEnterForeground gets found nil for textLabel

Tags: ios, swift, null, textlabel

I'm trying to change text on label when app will enter foreground but I always get

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
ViewController.swift

  @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    func showLabel() {
        textLabel.text = "Welcome back"
    }
```

and

```
AppDelegate.swift

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
       ViewController().showLabel()
    }
```

Any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Has that view controllers view been loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nil when unwrapping an Optional Value in didBecomeActive()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016699/nil-when-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-didbecomeactive)

Comment: yep this was my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016699/nil-when-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-didbecomeactive but I Couldn't find it before. It was asked today

Answer (score 2):

thanks for answers! I managed it with

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showLabel", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

in viewDidLoad

and then in AppDelegate

```
func showLabel() {}
```

based on :
[Nil when unwrapping an Optional Value in didBecomeActive()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016699/nil-when-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-didbecomeactive)

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016699/nil-when-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-didbecomeactive/28016942#28016942), you should initialize your label in the `viewDidLoad` function of your view controller.

In fact, at the time you are in `applicationWillEnterForeground`, your view controller has not been yet initialized, so the label textLabel is null (`nil`) and you are trying to access a property of a null object (reason of your error).

ViewController.swift:

```
@IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

func viewDidLoad() {
    textLabel.text = "Welcome back"
}
```

Comment: not working. I did it seceond after I saw the error but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you are creating a new instance of your `ViewController` and trying to set the data to it.

Instead of that use the existing one ( You created on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` )

Comment: I know that but how can I get access to the existing one?   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

Comment: @chrisco: If you are setting the ViewController from storyboard then, try the reverse mechanism (means from view control fetch the data from app delegate). Else set your ViewController as the rootViewController property of your application